# How to Find Where Exception is Happening

Tags: android, android-widget, illegalargumentexception

I am getting a random exception only after performing multiple, back to back operations on my app.  I have a list of locations I add at least 10 to, delete one, change the location 4 times, then try to enter a new one.  It is an AutoCompleteTextView that handles searching.  This is the error I am receiving.  When I go back into the app, all my locations are gone, but reappear if I open it again.  This is a HomeScreen app widget.

> 01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): Process: com.tara.client.diff.android, PID: 22653
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer{41c48ea0 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:370)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.dismiss(PopupWindow.java:1308)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.dismiss(ListPopupWindow.java:646)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1033)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.doAfterTextChanged(AutoCompleteTextView.java:786)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$MyWatcher.afterTextChanged(AutoCompleteTextView.java:745)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7424)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3822)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.tara.android.views.SimpleSearchView.clearInput(SimpleSearchView.java:163)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.tara.android.widgets.WidgetConfigurationActivity.handleSearchItemSelected(WidgetConfigurationActivity.java:279)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.tara.android.widgets.WidgetConfigurationActivity.onLocationSearchCompleted(WidgetConfigurationActivity.java:390)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.tara.android.utilities.Data.notifyLocationSearchCompleted(Data.java:601)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.tara.android.services.request.LocationKeySearchTask.onPostExecute(LocationKeySearchTask.java:93)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5109)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:800)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   01-18 13:08:54.903: E/AndroidRuntime(22653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spinner inside popup not opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670437/spinner-inside-popup-not-opening)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. This is not happening in my devices. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write some logs in order to check every step?

```
Log.d("passing through foo_function()","bar just read");
```

Comment: I tried writing some logs in the catch clause, but it didn't pass through the ones I wrote in.  I don't know where it is coming from.